# How to use "Landscape Eroder" on non-procedural landscape?

Tags: mesh, add-on, customization, displacement

I recently discovered the A.N.T. Landscape add-on and find the additional „Landscape Eroder“ tool very helpful to create a realistic impression.

Now I’m using an imported image to create a non-procedural landscape with the displacement modifier. To add some realistic details I want to use the „Landscape Eroder" on that mesh as well. But when I go to Weight Paint mode I can’t find the option.

So is there another way to use the „Landscape Eroder“ on a non-procedural landscape? Or is there another add-on for that reason?